# Windows composer install issue

Tags: php, windows, installation, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer via the composer-setup.exe from http://getcomposer.org/download/ and I'm getting the following error:

> > Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org
>
> Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors: SSL:
>   The operation completed successfully. . Send of 25 bytes failed with
>   errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. . Send of 23 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. . Send of 2 bytes
>   failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host. . Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

I tried disabling my antivirus/firewall but I keep on getting the same error. I searched google but couldn't resolve this. Any help here? Thanks.

Comment: enabled ssl extension?

Comment: if you mean 
extension=php_openssl.dll yes it is enabled

Answer (score 3):

Is SSL enabled in the correct php.ini?

If the installation approach via the windows executable fails,
you might switch to just downloading the `composer.phar` to your PHP dir, e.g. `C:\php\composer.phar`.

Then add `composer.bat` file inside the `C:\php` folder which forwards commands to the PHAR file:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Also add the path to your php directory (e.g. `C:\php`) to the `Path` in your System variables. This result in a global installaton of composer. You can call composer on any project path.