# Am getting this error message when trying to install composer on my pc(windows 10)

Tags: php, composer-php

I have PHP and Apache both installed as separate packages on my PC and am getting this error while trying to install composer.Could this be the issue?Should I use pre-packaged services like xampp or wamp?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKPP3.png

[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092967/windows-composer-install-issue

Answer (score 1):

You could check that you have the `php_openssl` extension activated in your `php.ini` file. There will likely be 2 `php.ini` file on your system, one in the `php` folder and one in the `apache/bin` folder. Activate `php_openssl` in both by removing the `#` comment character and then restarting Apache.

Comment: that was the first thing I did but still get the same error dialogue