# How to solve failed install composer laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Having problem when I installed composer laravel, like this...

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Please do not link only images, without clearly defining your problem first in the actual question itself.  Also, this does not appear to be about programming or development, and may be better suited for SuperUser, instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092967/windows-composer-install-issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981344 Or wait 5 minutes and try again

Comment: @Mizi To help you solve your problem would you be able to edit the question to provide more details. The command you used. And dump the output of the Command Line into pastebin or as code here. Then hopefully we can help you resolve your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in a comment above if you could provide us with some more detail in the commands you are using etc we will be able to provide you with more help. Nevertheless below are 2 methods you can use to install Laravel in a windows environment.

#### Method 1

So here you are installing the larval toolset. 1st command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Then make sure that you put the following in the PATH files of your computer `~/.composer/vendor/bin` so that windows can locate larval. Then you can use the following command:

```
laravel new blog
```

Which will create you a new laravel project in a new directory blog

#### Method 2

This method uses composer create-project to create the project without installing the larval executable. The command is:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} "5.0.*" --prefer-dist
```

Replace the star with a version number you want.

---

You can find out more information about both methods from https://laravel.com/docs/5.0

And again if you provide us with some more detail we can help you resolve the issue. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I'm sorry for my question is less clear. because I do not speak english

I had a problem, when I install laravel with the composer, I find problems as shown above.
steps I did, first download and install the composer
second, install composer from commandprompt (cmd) with the command "create-project composer laravel / laravel sampleApp --prefer-dist"
when I type the respective command error messages appear as above

Comment: @Mizi try `composer clear-cache` then try to install laravel also try `composer diagnose`

Comment: @Mizi has it worked? If you would you be able to mark my answer as the answer